# What is the best search Algorithm for PHP & MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to make a search for articles on my website -
is it ok to use just plain 'LIKE' statement or is there a better search algorithm to use with MySQL? (its important it be efficient)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should look into using [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).
It might also help you to read about the [Tradeoffs of MySQL LIKE vs Full-Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like)

Comment: Note: The MySQL link refers to the 5.0 documentation. In 5.0, FTS is only allowed on MyISAM tables. In MySQL versions >= 5.6, FTS is allowed on both MyISAM and InnoDB.

Answer (score 14):

> is it ok to use just plain 'LIKE' statement or is there a better
>   search algorithm to use with MySQL? (its important it be efficient)

### Like

If it is important to be efficient then I think [LIKE is absolutely not the way to go](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/12809.html).

> Full Text Search: 392 Sec Full Text Search (Cached): 272 Sec
>
> Full Text Boolean Mode 12 Sec Full Text Boolean (Cached) 11 Sec
>
> Mnogosearch (external) 3.5 Sec Mnogosearch (external cached) 1.06 Sec
>
> Sphinx 0.23 Sec Sphinx Cached 0.15 Sec
>
> LIKE %...% 30sec Sec  LIKE %...% (Cached) 29sec Sec

### [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Probably [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is the most efficient method, which also  has support for MySQL. To be honest I have never used [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) myself, but some very big sites use it.

[image]

It is probably more difficult to setup then another(probably last) alternative.

### [MySQL full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

I also think [MySQL full-text-search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) would probably be fast enough and a easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Using Apache Solr
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/
or Elastic Search
http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Comment: Could you expand your answer as to why these would be appropriate.  Otherwise it's just a link.