# Make single query for search full title and its words in PHP & MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I want to make a search for products based on whole title name and also title words. It's ok to use `LIKE` for searching product in mysql by using `UNION`. My database `title(charchar(550)) = Colorzone Men's Casual Wear Red Cotton Shirt` not a [Fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) --
[[What is the best search Algorithm for PHP & MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912345/what-is-the-best-search-algorithm-for-php-mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912345/what-is-the-best-search-algorithm-for-php-mysql)

But I need to below the search result(**First**:`Cotton Shirt` record, **Second** `Cotton` record and **Third**: `Shirt` record. Should not showing all the records mixed) as single query

**MYSQL Query:** For Ex: Title = `Cotton Shirt`

```
SELECT title FROM zapstore_ecom_products WHERE title LIKE '%Cotton Shirt%' //Get Whole Title products.
UNION
SELECT title FROM zapstore_ecom_products WHERE title LIKE '%Cotton%' //Get list for first word Title products.
UNION
SELECT title FROM zapstore_ecom_products WHERE title LIKE '%Shirt%' //Get list for last word Title products.
```

Suppose the user title have 4 or more words then it will make 4 or more query by using `UNION`. We will make this search with single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FULLTEXT search on `title` in boolean mode `against ('Cotton','Shirt')` and `ORDER BY score DESC`
This should give you your desired output

I didn't try mysql but according to theory explained in MySQL Doc it will work

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Its better to include some code examples to improve this answer