# MySQL FullText Search seems doesn't work

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
SELECT * FROM `pt_acf` WHERE `palavra` 
LIKE "%orai%"
```

Showing records # 0-29 (62 total, Query took 0.0608 seconds)

```
SELECT * FROM `pt_acf` WHERE MATCH(`palavra`)
AGAINST("orai")
```

Showing records # 0-17 (18 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds)

Why in LIKE search found 62 records and in FULLTEXT only 18?
The time is great but it didn't found all the records.

Answer (score 0):

This post might help you out with difference between fulltext search and like:

[What is Full Text Search vs LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like)

Comment: Oh thank you, this link is nice.