# SQL server freetexttable partial words

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL free text searching for the first time and I'm a little confused why it behaves the way it does.

I have a table of contacts which users can search and I'm using

```
SELECT Contacts.*, [Rank]
FROM 
FREETEXTTABLE (Contacts, *, 'O''Roarty') AS Contact1_ftt
JOIN Contacts ON Contacts.ContactID = Contact1_ftt.[Key]
```

which returns 2 results on people with "O'Roarty" as their surname. However if I search for "Roarty" I get no results at all. The same happens if I search for "Dave" I get results but "Dav" no results.

Its looks like partial words don't work. Is there a way to enable partial word matches as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing Full-Text search does not support suffix search. So you cannot search using `"*ave"`. Second regarding the uses of `LIKE`, `LIKE` AND `FTS` works differently. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN Question/Answer better explains the functionality than I can, so I'll just [link it here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17653360-2c72-4647-96f0-d3a2a9e67f0e/searching-partial-and-or-full-word-from-fulltext-search-those-might-be-precise-or-fuzzy-less).

You basically want to be using `CONTAINSTABLE` if you want partial word matches.

Comment: That allows me to do things like "Dav*" to return anything that starts with "Dav" including "Dave" but you cant do "*ave" as the * only works at the end. Plus it would require the users to enter this as their search string on the UI which I know they wont or write a function to format the string before its sent to SQL. Seems LIKE statements might suit this better.