# FreeTextTable returns no records

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, freetexttable

I have a flat table to perform Full Text Search and even the simplest search doesn't work. I have tried numerous things and I am getting same result. However surprising thing is that similar Full Text Search works on other tables in the same database.

Below is my table structure, I have also added Full Text Index details for quick reference.
[image: Table Structure and Full Text Options]

Below is the search result of my query, I have tried multiple things without any luck, the query only works when I provide exact value from the column.
[image: Search Result]
Search results are same even when I use one column i.e. Fname only in my query.

I may be missing some basic thing but I am not sure what that thing is. Below is the create table script for it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [IName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Contents] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LatestVersion] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'climate.c','climate_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'flowrout.c','validateTreeLayout','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'flowrout.c','validateGeneralLayout','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gage.c','gage_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gwater.c','gwater_validateAquifer','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gwater.c','gwater_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','lid_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','validateLidProc','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','validateLidGroup','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','link_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','conduit_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','pump_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','orifice_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','weir_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'node.c','node_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'node.c','divider_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'project.c','project_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'rdii.c','validateRdii','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'shape.c','shape_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'snow.c','snow_validateSnowmelt','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'subcatch.c','subcatch_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'table.c','table_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'transect.c','transect_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'climate.c','climate_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'flowrout.c','validateTreeLayout','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'flowrout.c','validateGeneralLayout','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gage.c','gage_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gwater.c','gwater_validateAquifer','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'gwater.c','gwater_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','lid_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','validateLidProc','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'lid.c','validateLidGroup','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','link_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','conduit_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','pump_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','orifice_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'link.c','weir_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'node.c','node_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'node.c','divider_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'project.c','project_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'rdii.c','validateRdii','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'shape.c','shape_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'snow.c','snow_validateSnowmelt','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'subcatch.c','subcatch_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'table.c','table_validate','',5);
insert into SampleTable (CID, VID, FID, TID, FName, IName, Contents, LatestVersion) values (-1,1,1,1,'transect.c','transect_validate','',5);
```

Please let me know if you  need more details.

Update 1:
So digging this further I found questions similar to mine.

- [sql server freetexttable partial words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138081/sql-server-freetexttable-partial-words)
- [FreeTextTable Ranked Search Not working for word](http://forums.asp.net/t/2023528.aspx?FreeTextTable%20Ranked%20Search%20Not%20working%20for%20word%20)

So if understood those URLs correctly then FreeTextTable doesn't work on one word which is surely not true as I am using one word query on another table and it works just fine.
[image: One word FTT query]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a substring match which FreeTextTable does not support. Instead, use [ContainsTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) with a wildcard.

```
select * from ContainsTable(SampleTable, ([FName],[IName]), 'clima*')
```

This search will match these strings:

- "climate.c"
- "climate.c blah blah"
- "blah blah climate.c"
- "blah blah climate.c blah blah"
- "clima"
- "blah blah clima"

But it *won't* match:

- "xxclimate"

FYI FreeTextTable is for natural language type searches -- synonyms, singular/plural forms, conjugations are matched and only 1 term in the search is required to match. ContainsTable matches the exact words (no synonyms, etc.), boolean operators are allowed (AND, OR, NOT), wildcards (*, ?) are supported, and you can perform proximity searches (word1 within N words of word2).

Comment: Thanks @Keith I am aware of ContainsTable and below will be the syntax for it 
select * from ContainsTable(SampleTable, [FName] , '"clima*"') however what I am looking for is to list any row which has "clima" in it whether beginning of the the string or towards end of the string so if I use ContaintsTable then it will only work for rows where "clima" is in beginning of the string.

Comment: @ndd It will match any row that contains a word beginning with "clima". See my edit for examples of what will be matched and what won't.

Comment: If you look the data you would notice that Fname and IName are one word columns i.e. it will never have space in it (except  "no abstract title" word, this is hard coded and holds C files declaration), to give you more details this table is holding C code and FName is file name and IName is function name I have changed the column names for creating this question.

Comment: @ndd It doesn't matter how many words are in the column. I recommend you try my suggestion to see if it works for you and let me know the results.

Comment: Please find results for the test http://i.stack.imgur.com/HfsMl.png it only shows rows where the names starts with the search term ('validate' in this example). From screen shot you would notice that like query gives more results than ContainsTable :)

Comment: I see. What you really need is to search on `*clima*` (or `*validate*` in the case of your screenshot). Unfortunately SQL Full Text does not support wildcards at the beginning of a word. You'll be better off doing a LIKE query `WHERE FName like '%clima%'...`

Comment: Because of this I want to use FreeTextTable instead of ContainsTable :)

Comment: You can't do wildcard matches with FreeTextTable so I think your only option is to use LIKE.