# Why is this code failing? mysql like problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I want to search in the mysql database. I want the search sent for search to be searched in 2 columns in the table. But I did not get results with this code.

```
$Ara = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE ? OR urun_kodu LIKE ?)");
$Ara->execute(array('%'.$Gelen.'%'));
while($Liste = $Ara->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){;
     $toplam_icerik = $Ara->rowCount();
}
```

where is the problem?

Comment: You need to have one value in your array for each parameter in the query. You have two parameters and only one value. Try changing `$Ara->execute(array('%'.$Gelen.'%'));` to `$Ara->execute(array('%'.$Gelen.'%', '%'.$Gelen.'%'));`

Comment: Try this `$Ara = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE :first OR urun_kodu LIKE :second)");  $Ara->bindValue(':first',         '%' . $Gelen . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);$Ara->bindValue(':second',         '%' . $Gelen . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Ara->execute();   $data = $Ara->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this,need to pass two values

```
$Ara = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE ? OR urun_kodu LIKE ?)");
$Ara->execute(array('%'.$Gelen.'%','%'.$Gelen.'%'));
while($Liste = $Ara->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){;
     $toplam_icerik = $Ara->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: @TurgutYıldırım For that, you need  FULL TEXT SEARCH see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: does SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE '%your value%' OR urun_kodu LIKE '%your value%') works in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You use two placeholders in the query, but pass only one parameter.
You must pass two parameters, for example:

```
$keyword = '%'.$Gelen.'%';
$Ara = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE ? OR urun_kodu LIKE ?)");
$Ara->execute(array($keyword, $keyword));
```

or you can use named placeholders. For example:

```
$keyword = '%'.$Gelen.'%';
$Ara = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_bilgileri WHERE (urun_adi LIKE :urun_adi OR urun_kodu LIKE :urun_kodu)");
$Ara->execute(array(':urun_adi' => $keyword, ':urun_kodu =>$keyword));
```

Comment: Named placeholders __must__ have different names, `:param`, `:param` will not work.

Comment: There are 1 search boxes. If I enter 'product name' here, look for its column. But if I enter 'product_code' here, search for the 'product_code' column.

Answer (score 0):

Enable PHP error_reporting and PDO error_reporting than PHP tells you this within an error message.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

and
http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.error-handling.php