# Is there any function for finding the result with special character in a sql like?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm try to get data from SQL using `LIKE` successful to get data but the result more than I need

Here is my some data

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
applejuice1
applej1
applej2
```

My query:

```
select * from apple where name like '%applej%'
```

Currently I got:

```
applejuice1
applej1
applej2
```

My Expected output:

```
applej1
applej2
```

Comment: Is `like 'applej_'` ok?

Comment: There are some answers involving using regular expressions. While that is useful for complex matching, I still would advise to use the LIKE operator's `_` wildcard character when possible. Regex expressions can be a performance killer and I am not sure if regex expressions can be used by indexes as well. (I know the LIKE operator can often make use of indexes, which is very preferrable.)

Comment: Can you explain that further? What do you mean by that "special character" in your title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) this is possbile:

```
select * 
from apple 
where `name` REGEXP '^applej[0-9]'
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2323b644523c89a4b28ebb9df0af68e7).

---

**Update:**

If the `name` has data as `applej1, applej2, applej15, applej109`, the following query will work:

```
select * 
from apple 
where `name` REGEXP '^applej[0-9]+'
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0e66b62a0d2c87327ddd8659ab2ff34)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
SELECT * FROM apple where name LIKE '%applej_'
```

'_' is used to represent a single character in SQL server.
For MS Access you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM apple where name LIKE '*applej?'
```

Comment: i don't want applejuice1, but your sql will return it

Comment: @TommyTang I doubt that very much... `SELECT * FROM apple where name LIKE '%applej_'` should work just fine. (It works fine on my MariaDB instance, at least...)

Comment: but if my data are applej1, applej15?

Comment: @TommyTang Yes, then it becomes more complex. The `_` wildcard represents just a single character, so to match `15`, you would need to use two of them. But that would also match `1a`, for example. And if you want to match `apple123456` with `'apple______'`, it will include `applejuice1` again. Here, you probably want to use a regex indeed.

Comment: @TommyTang  if you want to get applej15 or any two digit integer after applej you can use  `SELECT * FROM apple where name LIKE '%applej[0-9][0-9]'` or if you dont want to use any alphabets after applej you can do that using   
`'applej[^a-z]'` (`[]` represents single character)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression, this will include all rows containing 'applej' + 0 or 1 more character

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE  col1 REGEXP '^applej.?$'
```

This one will find all rows containing 'applej' + exactly 1 more character

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE  col1 REGEXP '^applej.{1}$'
```

And if the number after 'applej' might contain several digits

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE  col1 REGEXP '^applej[0-9]+$'
```

Of course maybe the LIKE suggested by @forpas in the comments above is all you need

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution with

```
SELECT * FROM apple WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('applej')
```

Comment: A full-text search... Yes, that might do the job as well. You may want to check it out somewhat further to decide if it really fits your needs in all respects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224714/what-is-full-text-search-vs-like